# Как правильно разместить if else

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть дополнительное поле в wordpress bloki
Как сделать так чтобы если они равные 3, то вывести цифру 4?
Это нужно чтобы выводить класс для блоков которые будут 3 т.е. класс col-md-4
и 4 то col-md-3 и 6 то col-md-2

```
<div class="col-md-<?php the_field('price'); ?>">
bla bla bla
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте проще. Сделайте это поле как radio button и для Лейблы "три" - значение 4, "две" - значение 6. И просто выводите значение как выводите
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Логично, спасибо за подсказку)